# How to create an app menu item to run TeamSpeak3 installed app

Tags: software-installation

I followed a tutorial from this forum to get TeamSpeak3 installed. Great! Then , to launch it from the menu, it instructed me to create a teamspeak.desktop file in the /usr/share/applications/ folder. Whenever I try using scratch, it won't let me save the file. I can place the same file in documents. I also tried to use chmod to change the permissions for the applications folder. It's not permitted.

Help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save or modify a file or folder as root you can open Files as root, right-click in Files and open Files as Administrator.

Also you can to open Scratch with sudo and save your file teamspeak.desktop in /usr/share/applications/ folder.

```
sudo scratch-text-editor
```

Of course if you want to create just a entry in the menu without be root, you can put your own .desktop files in "~/.local/share/applications/". It's more safe.